# What does the format %10.2 mean when included in a printf statement?

Tags: format, format-specifiers

What does the format %10.2 mean when included in a printf statement?
it has been asked in a interview which i failed to answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer will help you. Actually your format should be "%10.2f" instead "%10.2" .

Floating Point Number Formatting.

[image]

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.printf("%10.2f",15.2);
    System.out.println();
 }
```

}